# Tinymce is not working anymore after rendering backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tinymce

I am having troublewith TinyMCE v4 with backbone.js.
When I refresh the page the editor work fine but when i navigate with my router it dosent work

```
 APP.Views.AddEdit = Backbone.View.extend({
            el:'#addEditHolder',
            initialize: function() {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'saveModel');
                this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
                vent.on("model:save", this.saveModel, this);
                this.render();
                this.form = this.$('form');
                this.name = this.form.find('#addedit_name');
                this.description = this.form.find('#addedit_description');
            },
            template: APP.template2( 'addEditTemplate' ),
            render: function() {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: "textarea.richContent",
                    theme: "modern",
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 240
                });
                return this;
            },
            saveModel: function() {
                this.model.save({
                     name:this.name.val(),
                     description:this.description.val()
                },
                {
                    wait: true,
                    patch: true
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible answer ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/32235165/651987